# MySQL Select ID with count on where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm coming to you because I have a little trouble with a SQL query, I have the following table that stores the devices that connects to my app.

[image]

**I have to select all COIDTE (unique id) where for each COTCT (terminal id) the number of CHIVDX (subscriber id) different is less than 5.**

I try different query like this for example, but without any result..

```
SELECT COIDTE from  E£XU0.TH68 group by COTCT HAVING COUNT(CHIVDX) < 5
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide more detail with your question. For instance, what is the table name and give a sample of data. I assume the table you provided above is the structure of the database table you are querying.

You can retrieve this information with a nested query. First you return the each COTCT where the number of CHIVDX is less than 5 and then return all COIDTE links to these.

```
SELECT COIDTE FROM <TABLE_NAME> where COTCT IN (
    SELECT COTCT, CHIVDX FROM <TABLE_NAME> GROUP BY CHIVDX HAVING COUNT(CHIVDX) < 5
)
```

Comment: I know there is not a lot of information in my answer, however data are confidential and i can't post some example.

Thx for your help, your query seems to return the result expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
 SELECT COIDTE from  E£XU0.TH68 group by COIDTE, COTCT HAVING COUNT(CHIVDX)< 5
```